# UPDATE não atualiza tabela

Tags: php, mysql

Não estou conseguindo realizar o update dos meus campos. Onde estou errando?

Pego o `id` através de `GET` e consigo exibir os dados da tabela, mas não consigo atualizá-la.

**CAMPOS**

```
$id_destino = $_GET['id_destino'];
$destino = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['destino']);
$historia = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['historia']);
$geografia = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['geografia']);
$clima = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['clima']);
$cultura   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cultura']);

if($_POST['enviar']) {
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `destinos_pt` SET destino = '$destino', historia = '$historia', geografia = '$geografia', clima = '$clima', cultura = '$cultura'  WHERE id_destino = '$id_destino'");
    header("Location: dashboard.php");
}
```

**FORMULÁRIO**

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" name="destinosform" novalidate role="form">
</form>
```

O que há de errado que não consigo atualizar minha *table*?

Comment: Coloque $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `destinos_pt` SET destino = '$destino', historia = '$historia', geografia = '$geografia', clima = '$clima', cultura = '$cultura'  WHERE id_destino = '$id_destino'") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Existe a variável `$_POST['enviar']` no seu formulário?

Comment: Leitura importante: [How do you debug PHP scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/888/1287812)

Comment: Tens de especificar mais o teu código para podermos ver onde está o erro.

Comment: Cuidado com sql injection usando os parametros dessa forma, ou faça uma limpeza ou usa prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que percebi, **$_GET['id_destino'];** não está sendo setado. Faça isso e verifique se há algum valor sendo retornado: `var_dump($_GET['id_destino']);`

Caso esteja vazio, você deverá (se quiser mesmo usar essa mistura de GET e POST, mas não recomendo) mandar o id dentro da action do seu form.

E `$_POST['enviar']`? Ela existe dentro do seu form? Caso não exista, a condição não será satisfeita e o UPDATE não será executado.